# Data Stream in Java

Tags: java, file-io, network-programming, java-io

I am using Data Stream class in java to perform read and write operations. My question is I am not closing both the streams and not even flushing the data then how it is working properly.

**I mean to say if data is not flushed out of the DataOutputStream then how it is successfully reading the data from DataiInputStream.**

```
public class DataStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        try {
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("E:/output.in"));
            dataOutputStream.writeInt(12345);
            dataOutputStream.writeFloat(123.45F);
            dataOutputStream.writeLong(12345);

            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("E:/output.in"));

            int intValue = dataInputStream.readInt();
            float floatValue = dataInputStream.readFloat();
            long longValue = dataInputStream.readLong();

            System.out.println("int     = " + intValue);
            System.out.println("float = " + floatValue);
            System.out.println("long    = " + longValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Luck, probably.  If you don't flush and close, it _might_ flush the data fully, but it makes no such guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is I am not closing both the streams and not even flushing the data then how it is working properly.

Because neither `DataOutputStream` nor `FileOutputStream` is buffered.

Comment: But there are no guarantees about what the filesystem does with the data.

Comment: @teppic I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here. The reason for the behaviour the OP is experiencing is what I have stated here. File system behaviour is defined by the operating system, not by Java, but it is certainly  to be expected that data written to a file by any application will be available to be read subsequently by that application in most if not all current operating systems. There was one in the 1970s where files didn't even exist until they were closed, but that's a long time ago.